# is there a way to reference a constant in a yaml with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, internationalization, yaml

Is there a way to have my en.yml file contain a constant?

```
# en.yml
foo:
  bar:
    I love BAZ so much!

# initializers/constants.rb
BAZ = "stackoverflow.com"

I18n.t("foo.bar")
->  "I love stackoverflow.com so much!"
```

?

If not, is there a way to self reference the yaml file?

```
foo:
  bar:
    I love *baz* so much!
baz:
  stackoverflow.com

I18n.t("foo.bar")
->  "I love stackoverflow.com so much!"
```

Comment: https://github.com/markbates/yamler

Comment: **See also**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620674/use-placeholders-in-yaml

Answer (score 8):

The I18N string tools support [interpolation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#interpolation):

```
I18n.t('foo.bar', :baz => 'stackoverflow.com')
```

And then in the `en.yml`:

```
foo:
  bar:
    I love %{baz} so much!
```

Just don't try to use `%{default}` or `%{scope}` as variables in your strings, `I18n.translate` uses those for other things:

> If a translation uses `:default` or `:scope` as an interpolation variable, an `I18n::ReservedInterpolationKey` exception is raised.

This doesn't apply to YAML in general but your question seems to be specifically about the translation files.

Comment: I tried finding this interpolation thing, good to have the link.

Comment: Hmmm..  Ok.  I was hoping for an easy way to have values automatically interpolated without having to supply them as an argument to the calls to I18n.translate...

Comment: @patrick: That would lead to all sorts of crazy non-local behavior and strange bugs. Too much magic is a bad thing.